# Change CellReuseIdentifier Based on section

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xib, reuseidentifier

I have a UITableView and a number of .xibs with different table view styles. Each .xib has it's own class and is registered with a reuse identifier based on the section. For example:
In my viewDidLoad I have the following:

```
UINib *cellStyleOne = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CellStyleOne" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:cellStyleOne forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellStyleOne"];

UINib *cellStyleTwo = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CellStyleTwo" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:cellStyleTwo forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellStyleTwo"];

UINib *cellStyleThree = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CellStyleThree" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:cellStyleThree forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellStyleThree"];
```

How would I assign each one of these reuse identifiers to a section of cells in my cellForRowAtIndexPath without causing any issues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can return any cell you like inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, just do something like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        //create and return a cell with reuse ID: @"CellStyleOne"
    }
    else 
    {
        //create and return a cell using a different reuse ID
    }
}
```